# How can we filter out tweets from Twitter that contains assertions

Tags: python, twitter, nlp

//For my project, I first collected tweets(specific count) using Python and Tweepy

//Did pre-processing to keep meaningful data.

//The next step is to search for tweets which have assertive sentences.
Please Help

Answer (score 0):

The term assertive is rather relative. However, you have to define certain boundaries for what you think assertiveness is.

I would then gather a few phrases or words that I think are assertive, and use them to filter the existing tweets.